# Missing switch for SwitchPreferenceCompat

Tags: android, preferencefragment

I have created a PreferenceScreen as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/title_telephone">

        <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:key="checkbox_preference_telephone_recording"
            android:title="@string/checkbox_telephone_recording"
            android:defaultValue="@string/default_checkbox_telephone_recording"/>

        <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:key="checkbox_preference_telephone_accel"
            android:title="@string/checkbox_telephone_accel"
            android:defaultValue="@string/default_checkbox_telephone_accel"/>

    </android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

However, for some reason I cannot find, the switches are not displayed. I do not get any errors. This is how it looks like:

[image]

---

**Code**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    private Preference mListPreference;


    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

---

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
        <item name="preferenceStyle">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_material_light</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_light</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
        <item name="preferenceStyle">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: The defaultValue attribute should take a boolean value not string

Comment: That does not matter. The provided resources are boolean values

Comment: can you post the code for your PreferenceFragment

Comment: move `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);` to the onCreate of the fragment. I always put mine there

Comment: apart from that, I think everything looks fine

Comment: Did you add these to your manifestTheme: `<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
        <item name="preferenceStyle">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>` then check your colourAccent attribute: the colour you set for it is the one that the switch would use

Comment: I have this one: `<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
`. But yours did not work either

Comment: ok but what of the colourAccent?

Comment: I will just add the full styles.xml here.

Comment: What colour is @colour/colourAccent?

Comment: @NezSpencer #FF009688

Comment: If I do not use the Switch from the v7 library, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Creating my own PreferenceTheme seemed to solve my problem, which is similar to the problem you're seeing.

If this doesn't do it, at least it shows how to create your own preferences theme so you can override other properties :)

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceTheme</item>
        <item name="preferenceStyle">@style/PreferenceTheme</item>
        ...
    </style>

    <style name="PreferenceTheme" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```